# Should I Create a Table or a Query?

Tags: sql, delphi

OK, I have an Access DB that have an Items Table and a Students Table that contains the monthly subscription fee, this two is linked in a third Table "Payments", that gathers the data from a Student(fee + items) and sum them. But that table only keeps the values and not the description. As the payment is irregular(the student don't need to pay all in the same day), and because of this the student's item debt value needs to be reduced as the way he pays, I need a control of that. So, should I create a new table that copies the data from two other tables and make the changes in this new one, or just use a query to show the data and makes the changes in the "main" table? I'm a bit lost and confuse in this, so sorry this mess.

Comment: Oh, the problem with creating a new table is that there is no way to know how much items a students will have.

Comment: It sounds like you're copying a lot of data across tables here (which is generally a bad idea), and it's really confusing what you're actually trying to do.  Maybe you can show a simple example?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read a beginner's text about database design before you go any further with this project, imo.  The first item found by googling "relational database tutorial" is

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html

see the section "Create Relationships among Tables". There are countless other tutorials online.

As  rule, you don't copy data from one table to another.  A piece of information like an item's description nor a user's name should only be stored in one place in a database.  When you need that in the context of relating it to data in another table (e.g. to display the description of an entry in the Items table with the cost amount in the Fees or Payments table), you look it up, not copy it.

The way to deal with a student having arbitarily many items is to have a "link" table that mainly stores only a unique identifier of the student and a unique identifier of the Item.  Usually, these would be numeric identifiers that are assigned as now student/item/other entities are added to the db.

The point of having a link table is that there is no practical limit to the number of items that can be associated with a particular student.

You call add a column to the link table to relate the student and one or more instance of the same item to particular bills (or or orders or whatever it is that your db is modelling).

Comment: Sorry, actualy i don't mean copy,  but link, yes. I link this multiple tables with the id and everything is working fine. The only problem is with the irregular payment thing.

Comment: Well, you need to tell us what is the problem with irregular payments?  What "business rules" are you trying to apply to them, and why is it a problem?

Comment: OK, normally when you have this kind of subscription + items, all of them sums in the end of the month and you pay the value, right? Here you only need pay the subscription. For the item, let's suppose that it's a gym and you buy a shirt, it's price is $10, but you can pay this value any day in the month, and you can pay like $2 in the monday, $7 in the wednesday and $1 on friday. I know this does not make any sense, but it's the way the owner works.

Comment: All this stuff should really be in your q, that's why its being downvoted and has 4 votes-to-close.  Anyway if you have a table of debits (userid, amounts and dates) and a table of payments (userid, amounts and dates), simple Sql queries will be about to tell you what a user has been charged in a given month and what he owes at the end of the month, or as of "today".  None of this stuff is difficult, you just need to be methodical.

Comment: I think the easier way here is sort the items that have the same student id and then make the discounts separately for each item. Anyways sorry for the mess and to take your time, you just cleared my thougts. I will close this now.